# processing line breaks

Tags: c#, string, user-interface, textbox

I'm creating a program in C# that goes through a string and calculate the frequency of characters in it.

Basically I have 2 class

```
    class Node
    {
       private char character;
       private float frequency;
       public void increment();//increments frequency
    }

    class FreqTbl
    {
        private List<Node> nodes;
        public void buildTable(char Symbol)
        {
            bool found = false;

       
            foreach (var node in nodes.Where(n => n.getSymbol() == Symbol))
            {
                node.increment();

                found = true;
            }

            if(found == false)
            {
                newNode(Symbol);
            }
        }
    }
```

Through a text box GUI, The program passes a char into FreqTbl.buildTable , which search through the nodes field. While all other characters are processed no problem, line breaks appears twice in the output

Say if the text box have the input

> linked list
>
> red black tree

The resultant output would be

> l:3
>
> i:2
>
> n:1
>
> k:2
>
> e:4
>
> d:2
>
> :3
>
> s:1
>
> t:2
>
> \n
>
> :1
>
> \n
>
> :1
>
> r:2
>
> b:1
>
> a:1
>
> c:1

\n represents the line break. Anyway to fix this so that only 1 line breaks appear in the output?

Comment: It seems you have two nodes which both represent \n. Eliminate one of them. Or (less likely) you might just have a bug in your output routine...

Comment: Why don't you trim end of the input string to make sure you don't get trailing `\n`

Comment: There's a lot of code missing from this example: `Node.increment()` is unimplemented and `FreqTbl.nodes` is inaccessible for output, there are no `newNode` or `getSymbol` methods defined, and that's just to start... still, going to see if I can reproduce with minimal edits...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before passing each char into FreqTbl.buildTable you have option to process your input:

```
string strInput = textBox1.Text.TrimEnd('\r', '\n' );
```

Or

```
string strInput = textBox1.Text.TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
```